# Trying to Play Riptide by Vance Joy but the chords sound like the wrong ones

Tags: guitar, acoustic-guitar

I just got a guitar and I am learning how to play riptide by vance joy and here is what I am following https://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/tab/vance-joy/riptide-chords-1237247.

For some reason when I play those chords in standard tuning of EADGBE with a capo on the first fret, it doesn't come together to sound like riptide. Instead, it does when I play the chords Em, Dsus2, and G.

I've noticed that the guitar doesn't sound quite right in standard tune for other songs either and I have to capo it beyond what the tutorial recommends. Is there anyway to fix this--is my tuning off or something?

Comment: Just 'cos it's on the 'net doesn't mean it's absolutely correct..!

Answer (score 1):

Leaving aside the sus2, this is almost certainly a tuning problem with your guitar. The chords you've given that sound correct are exactly a fifth (seven frets) higher than the ones given on the web page. That would also explain why you need to move your capo so far.